# Call variable in for loop - BATCH

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I would like to know if it's possible or other ways to get this:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 SET loopcount=3

 SET variable1=test1
 SET variable2=test2
 SET variable3=test3

 for /l %%x in (1, 1, %loopcount%) do {
      echo %variable%%x%
 }
```

As you can see in echo, I want to get the value of variable1 which is `test1` and so on... Is there any workaround on this? Thank you.

Comment: Try `call echo %%variable%%x%%` or `echo !variable%%x!`

Comment: or even: `For /L %%x in (1 1 3)Do For /F "Tokens=2* Delims==" %%G in (' Set "Variable%%x" 2^> nul ')Do Echo(%%G`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to perform your task, is to use delayed expansion.

In your example you already enabled it, but didn't use it. A delayed variable is enclosed within `!` characters, as opposed to `%` characters.

Example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "loopcount=3"

Set "variable1=test1"
Set "variable2=test2"
Set "variable3=test3"

For /L %%G In (1,1,%loopcount%) Do (
    Echo(!variable%%G!
)
```

However, you should wherever possible, you should only enable delayed expansion, when needed:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "loopcount=3"

Set "variable1=test1"
Set "variable2=test2"
Set "variable3=test3"

For /L %%G In (1,1,%loopcount%) Do (
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!variable%%G!
    EndLocal
)
```

Comment: @DockerJava-Guy, if this is the best answer, please select the check mark to indicate that to other people. This is how SO works.